# After integrate ssl in wordpress edit post is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

After integrate ssl certificate in wordpress, Got an error while updating the post, page or widget. Here is the error I got while update.

> Access Denied
>       You don't have permission to access "http://blog/wp-admin/post.php" on this server.
>
> Reference #18.2d7c4117.1499779174.7a397178

I check with the file permission. All the files are 644 and folders are 755 as suggested in wordpress. Help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the address in the error - it is not `https://` and it should be.

Comment: @jay blanchard : I changed the url to https:// in general settings. Also I check with the database, there is no http://

Comment: You don't integrate SSL into Wordpress, but into the underlying web-server. You should at least state, which server you are using (Apache? nginx?) and if there is some output in the web-servers error log-files.

Comment: @feeela I integrate ssl into server only. I am using apache server